# MSGraph passport.js for OIDC strategy not working in typescript environment

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

So I am building an express server in Typescript, as I am a big fan of Typescript. (Thx to Angular)
Now I wanted to migrate my Microsoft Graph integration from Javascript to Typescript and there is a weird issue going on with this.

For some reason if I have this bit of code:

```ts
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import passport from 'passport';

export function m365Login(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  passport.authenticate("azuread-openidconnect", {
    response: res,
    prompt: "login",
    state: req.query.state,
    failureRedirect:
      process.env.WEBSITE_URL! + "settings?error=incorrect_request",
    successRedirect: process.env.WEBSITE_URL! + "settings?auth=success",
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

It gives me the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(strategy: string | Strategy | string[], callback?: AuthenticateCallback | ((...args:
any[]) => any) | undefined): any', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ response: Response<any, Record<string, any>>; prompt: string; state: string |
QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[] | undefined; failureRedirect: string;
successRedirect: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AuthenticateCallback | ((...args:
any[]) => any) | undefined'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'response' does not exist in type 
'AuthenticateCallback | ((...args: any[]) => any)'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(strategy: string | Strategy | string[], options: AuthenticateOptions, callback?: 
AuthenticateCallback | ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined): any', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | 
undefined'.
      Type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)

index.d.ts(173, 9): The expected type comes from property 'state' which is declared here on type
'AuthenticateOptions'
```

According to the documentation on using OIDC strategy for Microsoft Graph with passport-azure-ad it should be possible to use those variables there.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!